# Office.js Get comments from Word online

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am developing with `Word AddIn` with `Office.js`, I am trying to get all comments in the `Word Document`.

I checked the msdn document and find it might be related with [comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.documentproperties?view=office-js#comments), but I fail to find any official docuemnt to use `comments` property.

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as i know, word api does not provide such function yet. the comment properties you found is the document properties comment.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXeLC.jpg)

Comment: Is there any way to get **comments** by *ooxml**?